# getaddrinfo linux manpage server example but using TCP instead of UDP

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, network-programming

I'm trying to convert the [server program example from getaddrinfo's linux manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) from UDP to TCP.

When running the program without any change first, I can communicate with a netcat client using UDP :

```
gcc main.c
./a.out 1234
```

```
netcat -u 127.0.0.1 1234
// this works here, I can send messages to the server
```

Then if I try with TCP :

```
netcat 127.0.0.1 1234
```

**^ this doesn´t connect and exists directly**

I tried to change some attributes in the `addrinfo` struct :

```
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; /* Stream socket */
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;    /* For wildcard IP address */
```

And it doesn´t connect either.

Here is the whole code :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 500

    int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
    int sfd, s;
    struct sockaddr_storage peer_addr;
    socklen_t peer_addr_len;
    ssize_t nread;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s port\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; /* Stream socket */
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;    /* For wildcard IP address */
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;          /* Any protocol */
    hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
    hints.ai_addr = NULL;
    hints.ai_next = NULL;

    s = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &hints, &result);
    if (s != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* getaddrinfo() returns a list of address structures.
       Try each address until we successfully bind(2).
       If socket(2) (or bind(2)) fails, we (close the socket
       and) try the next address. */

    for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) {
        sfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype,
                rp->ai_protocol);
        if (sfd == -1)
            continue;

        if (bind(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) == 0)
            break;                  /* Success */

        close(sfd);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);           /* No longer needed */

    if (rp == NULL) {               /* No address succeeded */
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not bind\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Read datagrams and echo them back to sender */

    for (;;) {
        peer_addr_len = sizeof(peer_addr);
        nread = recvfrom(sfd, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0,
                (struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr, &peer_addr_len);
        if (nread == -1)
            continue;               /* Ignore failed request */

        char host[NI_MAXHOST], service[NI_MAXSERV];

        s = getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr,
                peer_addr_len, host, NI_MAXHOST,
                service, NI_MAXSERV, NI_NUMERICSERV);
        if (s == 0)
            printf("Received %zd bytes from %s:%s\n",
                    nread, host, service);
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "getnameinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));

        if (sendto(sfd, buf, nread, 0,
                    (struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr,
                    peer_addr_len) != nread)
            fprintf(stderr, "Error sending response\n");
    }
}
```

How to make this server program accept TCP connections with netcat ?

Comment: The TCP protocol is different from the UDP protocol. With TCP your server needs to listen for incoming connections using `accept`, which spawns a connected socket that you need to call `send` and `recv` for, rather than `sendto` and `recvfrom`. It is not "just" switching protocols.

Comment: ok I managed to get it working, thanks !